# Where is glGenBuffers in Qt5?

Tags: qt, opengl, opengl-es, qt5

I can't seem to find the `glGenBuffer` function in Qt5, my include list looks like

```
#include <QtOpenGL/qgl.h>
#include <QtOpenGL/qglbuffer.h>
#include <QtOpenGL/qglcolormap.h>
#include <QtOpenGL/qglframebufferobject.h>
#include <QtOpenGL/qglfunctions.h>
#include <QtOpenGL/qglpixelbuffer.h>
#include <QtOpenGL/qglshaderprogram.h>
#include <GL/GLU.h>
```

I am trying to do something like the following example:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtopengl/cube.html

Where is it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know I'm late, but here's a more elegant solution (you don't need GLEW =))

in addition to making sure you have `QT += opengl` in your *.pro file, and that your version of Qt has OpenGL, and that you have `#include <QGLFunctions>` (you don't need all of those includes that you listed down above; just this one line) in your header file, you need one more thing.

So given you have a class that calls all these functions:

```
class MeGlWindow : public QGLWidget
{
   // bla bla bla...
}
```

You need to inherit a protected class [QGLFunctions](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qglfunctions.html):

```
class MeGlWindow : public QGLWidget, protected QGLFunctions // add QGLFunctions
{
   // bla bla bla...
}
```

ALSO, just as GLEW required `glewInit()` to be called once before you call the OpenGL functions, `QGLFunctions` requires you to call `initializeGLFunctions()`. So for example, in `QGLWidget`, `initializeGL()` is called once before it starts drawing anything:

```
void MeGlWindow::initializeGL()
{
    initializeGLFunctions();

    // ...now you can call your OpenGL functions!
    GLuint myBufferID;
    glGenBuffers(1, &myBufferID);

    // ...
}
```

Now you should be able to call `glGenBuffers`, `glBindBuffer`, `glVertexAttribPointer` or whatever openGL function without GLEW.

**UPDATE**:
Certain OpenGL functions like `glVertexAttribDivisor` and `glDrawElementsInstanced` do not work with `QGLFunctions`. This is because `QGLFunctions` only provides functions specific to OpenGL/ES 2.0 API, which may not have these features.

To work around this you could use [QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qopenglfunctions-4-3-core.html)(or similar) which is only available since Qt 5.1. Replace `QGLFunctions` with `QOpenGLFunctions_4_3_Core`, and `initializeGLFunctions()` with `initializeOpenGLFunctions()`.

Comment: Yes, is exactly how I'm doing the work nowdays, although I wonder which one is better. It is not unreasonable to expect GLEW to do a better job finding nvidia specific functions.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source for the example you cited:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtopengl/cube-geometryengine-h.html

It has:

```
#include <QGLFunctions>
```

Which does have `glGenBuffers`

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtopengl/qglfunctions.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtopengl/qglfunctions.html#glGenBuffers

Hope that helps!

Comment: If it were that easy I wouldn't be asking the question :-). I don't have a include matching `#include <QGLFunctions>`, the closest is `#include <QtOpenGL/qglfunctions.h>`, which doesn't work.

Comment: Does your .pro file have the right stuff?  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtopengl/cube-cube-pro.html  Such as `QT += opengl`?

Answer (score 1):

If you add `QT += opengl` to your project (.pro) file, you will find that you don't need to specify the folder of each header you're importing, *and* you will be able to use `#include <QGLFunctions>` right away.

The advantage of using `QGLFunctions` over GLEW is that you are sure your application can be compiled on any platform and will not depend on where on your system your GLEW libraries are hidden: the Qt libraries will do this for you. As @phyatt pointed out, Qt's Cube example is a good example to see how to use this library.

Comment: I have bleeding edge version of QT (from the git) and I don't think this is correct, in the examples in my `examples` folder there is a class in `glextensions` in every project that uses `glBindBuffers` that performs wrangling like GLEW.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question in the examples folder.

Specifically, it was necessary to copy a header called `glextensions.h` which functions like GLEW.

I ended up using GLEW.